# Eclipse doesn't execute the right branch

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have just pulled a project from git into my freshly installed Eclipse (I'm using Ubuntu, if that matters).
I have two branches, both cloned locally. However, when I change the branch and try to execute the second branch, Eclipse will still execute the former branch, even though it's not checked out. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: are both branches open on eclipse in different folders?

Comment: no, they are in the same folder.

Comment: have you made changes to the first branch, or committed them?

Comment: open and close eclipse?

Comment: no, also restarting Eclipse had sadly no effect :(

Comment: go to run-> run configuration then select your new class?

Comment: How are you "changing the branch"? Does Eclipse show the branch you expect in its views?

Comment: Yes, it does. It even shows the correct files and the differences in the files. I have checked my previous computer and there Eclipse will run the right branch on execution. So why not now?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally figured out what the problem was. There was a file that should have been in the repo, but wasn't. It was required for the build on runtime.

It's a bit annoying that this wasn't pointed out by Eclipse, other than with a small exclamation mark next to the project folder. I finally spotted that (blind me) and googled what it meant. Suprise, surprise, file missing for the build!

I added that and everything compiled fine...